# Confirmation about how to formally state a function rule that satisfies a specific property

Tags: functions

I am having a little trouble deciding that I have properly worded the rule for a function. The only background knowledge required is as follows:

> Let $G$ be any subset of $X \times Y$ with the property that for each $x \in X$, the set $\{y \in Y: (x,y) \in G\}$ has exactly one element.

Now, the function that I am trying to make can be worded as:

"$f$ maps each element of $X$ to its ordered pair 'partner component' found in $G$."

Here is how I have tried to word this:

$f: X \to Y$

$f: \forall x \in X, f(x) = y \text{ such that } (x,y) \in G$

Because of how $G$ is defined, I think this is satisfactory. But I am uncertain about whether or not my formal language has correctly encoded the idea of mapping each first component of the ordered pair to its   partner second component.

Confirmation would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is indeed how it works. Because it is unique we call the unique $y$ with $(x,y) \in G$ the image $f(x)$ of $x$.

Or $y=f(x)=\pi_2[G \cap (\{x\}\times Y)]$, where $\pi_2$ is the projection from $X \times Y$ onto $Y$.